# OpenCV detect blobs on the image

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I need to find *(and draw rect around)/get max and min radius* blobs on the image. *(samples below)*

the problem is to find correct filters for the image that will allow `Canny` or `Threshold` transformation to highlight the blobs. then I going to use `findContours` to find the rectangles.

I've tryed:

- `Threshold` - with different level
- `blur->erode->erode->grayscale->canny`
- change [image tone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102385/opencv-tone-curve-progrommatically) with variety of "lines"

and ect. the better result was to detect piece (20-30%) of blob. and this info not allowed to draw rect around blob. also, thanks for shadows, not related to blob dots were detected, so that also prevents to detect the area.

as I understand I need to find counter that has hard contrast (not smooth like in shadow). Is there any way to do that with openCV?

***Update***

cases separately: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbNth.png), [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsXs9.png), [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wiLx.png), [image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6997.png), [image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHxy4.jpg), [image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy8La.jpg), [image 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APStv.jpg), [image 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY1cx.jpg), [image 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyzfh.png), [image 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDFCi.jpg), [image 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPDN2.jpg), [image 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9kOt.jpg)

***One more Update***

I believe that the blob have the contrast area at the edge. So, I've tried to make edge stronger: I've created 2 `gray scale Mat: A and B`, apply `Gaussian blur` for the second one - `B` *(to reduce noise a bit)*, then I've made some calculations: goes around every pixel and find max difference between `Xi,Yi` of 'A' and nearby dots from 'B':

[image]

and apply `max` difference to `Xi,Yi`. so I get smth like this:

[image]

is i'm on the right way? btw, can I reach smth like this via OpenCV methods?

***Update*** [Image Denoising](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html) helps to reduce noize, `Sobel` - to highlight the contours, then `threshold` + `findContours` and `custome convexHull` gets smth similar I'm looking for but it not good for some blobs.

Comment: Why the input is in form of collage, Is this original input format? or you have created one by yourself in order to show different variety of cases?

Comment: @ZdaR yes, I've created it to show different variety of cases. There is not all possible variants (but i hope most popular)

Comment: Can you upload all the cases seperately ?

Comment: @ZdaR, uploaded input files to `i.stack.imgur.com` separately, thank you

Comment: congrats, you have just (re)discovered high-pass filter! when you subtract the gaussian blur from the original, you get high response on the edges... specifically what makes it hard is that the reflections has sharp edges too.

Comment: I don't know if it is over killing in your project, but you can train and use a cascade classifier. You can start from here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

Comment: @Eran W, thank you. now i know how it's called (and got smth similar with `Sobel`). @evi, thank you. will check!

Comment: @user5599807 consider accepting an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are big differences between the input images, the algorithm should be able to adapt to the situation. Since Canny is based on detecting high frequencies, my algorithm treats the sharpness of the image as the parameter used for preprocessing adaptation. I didn't want to spend a week figuring out the functions for all the data, so I applied a simple, linear function based on 2 images and then tested with a third one. Here are my results:

[image: first result]

[image: second result]

[image: third result]

Have in mind that this is a very basic approach and is only proving a point. It will need experiments, tests, and refining. The idea is to use Sobel and sum over all the pixels acquired. That, divided by the size of the image, should give you a basic estimation of high freq. response of the image. Now, experimentally, I found values of clipLimit for CLAHE filter that work in 2 test cases and found a **[linear function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9.80%20*%20a%20%2B%20b%20%3D%201.5;%208.04%20*%20a%20%2B%20b%20%3D%206)** connecting the high freq. response of the input with a CLAHE filter, yielding good results.

```
sobel = get_sobel(img)
clip_limit = (-2.556) * np.sum(sobel)/(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]) + 26.557
```

That's the adaptive part. Now for the contours. It took me a while to figure out a correct way of filtering out the noise. I settled for a simple trick: using contours finding twice. First I use it to filter out the unnecessary, noisy contours. Then I continue with some morphological magic to end up with correct blobs for the objects being detected (more details in the code). The final step is to filter bounding rectangles based on the calculated mean, since, on all of the samples, the blobs are of relatively similar size.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def unsharp_mask(img, blur_size = (5,5), imgWeight = 1.5, gaussianWeight = -0.5):
    gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5,5), 0)
    return cv2.addWeighted(img, imgWeight, gaussian, gaussianWeight, 0)


def smoother_edges(img, first_blur_size, second_blur_size = (5,5), imgWeight = 1.5, gaussianWeight = -0.5):
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, first_blur_size, 0)
    return unsharp_mask(img, second_blur_size, imgWeight, gaussianWeight)


def close_image(img, size = (5,5)):
    kernel = np.ones(size, np.uint8)
    return cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)


def open_image(img, size = (5,5)):
    kernel = np.ones(size, np.uint8)
    return cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)


def shrink_rect(rect, scale = 0.8):
    center, (width, height), angle = rect
    width = width * scale
    height = height * scale
    rect = center, (width, height), angle
    return rect


def clahe(img, clip_limit = 2.0):
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=clip_limit, tileGridSize=(5,5))
    return clahe.apply(img)


def get_sobel(img, size = -1):
    sobelx64f = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,2,0,size)
    abs_sobel64f = np.absolute(sobelx64f)
    return np.uint8(abs_sobel64f)


img = cv2.imread("blobs4.jpg")
# save color copy for visualizing
imgc = img.copy()
# resize image to make the analytics easier (a form of filtering)
resize_times = 5
img = cv2.resize(img, None, img, fx = 1 / resize_times, fy = 1 / resize_times)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# use sobel operator to evaluate high frequencies
sobel = get_sobel(img)
# experimentally calculated function - needs refining
clip_limit = (-2.556) * np.sum(sobel)/(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]) + 26.557

# don't apply clahe if there is enough high freq to find blobs
if(clip_limit < 1.0):
    clip_limit = 0.1
# limit clahe if there's not enough details - needs more tests
if(clip_limit > 8.0):
    clip_limit = 8

# apply clahe and unsharp mask to improve high frequencies as much as possible
img = clahe(img, clip_limit)
img = unsharp_mask(img)

# filter the image to ensure edge continuity and perform Canny
# (values selected experimentally, using trackbars)
img_blurred = (cv2.GaussianBlur(img.copy(), (2*2+1,2*2+1), 0))
canny = cv2.Canny(img_blurred, 35, 95)

# find first contours
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# prepare black image to draw contours
canvas = np.ones(img.shape, np.uint8)
for c in cnts:
    l = cv2.arcLength(c, False)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    aspect_ratio = float(w)/h

    # filter "bad" contours (values selected experimentally)
    if l > 500:
        continue
    if l < 20:
        continue
    if aspect_ratio < 0.2:
        continue
    if aspect_ratio > 5:
        continue
    if l > 150 and (aspect_ratio > 10 or aspect_ratio < 0.1):
        continue
    # draw all the other contours
    cv2.drawContours(canvas, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

# perform closing and blurring, to close the gaps
canvas = close_image(canvas, (7,7))
img_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(canvas, (8*2+1,8*2+1), 0)
# smooth the edges a bit to make sure canny will find continuous edges
img_blurred = smoother_edges(img_blurred, (9,9))
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
# erode to make sure separate blobs are not touching each other
eroded = cv2.erode(img_blurred, kernel)
# perform necessary thresholding before Canny
_, im_th = cv2.threshold(eroded, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
canny = cv2.Canny(im_th, 11, 33)

# find contours again. this time mostly the right ones
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# calculate the mean area of the contours' bounding rectangles
sum_area = 0
rect_list = []
for i,c in enumerate(cnts):
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    _, (width, height), _ = rect
    area = width*height
    sum_area += area
    rect_list.append(rect)
mean_area = sum_area / len(cnts)

# choose only rectangles that fulfill requirement:
# area > mean_area*0.6
for rect in rect_list:
    _, (width, height), _ = rect
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box * 5)
    area = width * height

    if(area > mean_area*0.6):
        # shrink the rectangles, since the shadows and reflections
        # make the resulting rectangle a bit bigger
        # the value was guessed - might need refinig
        rect = shrink_rect(rect, 0.8)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box * resize_times)
        cv2.drawContours(imgc, [box], 0, (0,255,0),1)

# resize for visualizing purposes
imgc = cv2.resize(imgc, None, imgc, fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)
cv2.imshow("imgc", imgc)
cv2.imwrite("result3.png", imgc)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Overall I think that's a very interesting problem, a little bit too big to be answered here. The approach I presented is due to be treated as a road sign, not a complete solution. Tha basic idea being:

1. Adaptive preprocessing.
2. Finding contours twice: for filtering and then for the actual classification.
3. Filtering the blobs based on their mean size.

Thanks for the fun and good luck!

Comment: thank you! great answer. is it possible to add bounty one more time?

Comment: @user5599807 I have no idea :) You're welcome - it was a lot of fun.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code I used:

```
import cv2
from sympy import Point, Ellipse
import numpy as np
x1='C:\\Users\\Desktop\\python\\stack_over_flow\\XsXs9.png'    
image = cv2.imread(x1,0)
image1 = cv2.imread(x1,1)
x,y=image.shape
median = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(9,9),0)
median1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(21,21),0)
a=median1-median
c=255-a
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(c,12,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel=np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1,kernel,iterations = 1)
kernel=np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('D:\\test12345.jpg',opening)
ret,contours,hierarchy =    cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c=np.size(contours[:])
Blank_window=np.zeros([x,y,3])
Blank_window=np.uint8(Blank_window)
for u in range(0,c-1):
    if (np.size(contours[u])>200):
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[u])
        (center,axes,orientation) =ellipse
        majoraxis_length = max(axes)
        minoraxis_length = min(axes)
        eccentricity=(np.sqrt(1-(minoraxis_length/majoraxis_length)**2))
        if (eccentricity<0.8):
             cv2.drawContours(image1, contours, u, (255,1,255), 3)
cv2.imwrite('D:\\marked.jpg',image1)
```

[image: this is the output image]

Here problem is to find a **near** circular object. This simple solution is based on finding the eccentricity for each and every contour. Such objects being detected is the drop of water.

Comment: Nice approach using eccenricity.

Comment: I don't think this actually solves the problem. The author of this answer only used few of the simplest cases. The problem here is mainly in the reflections, different background and overall noise. These operations will - in my opinion - fail with at least 30% of the cases shown in the question. [Used the code for one of the cases](http://imgur.com/s527pRM)

Comment: yep, this is not applied for the all images, but looks the truth - it should be  several algorithms and logic to detect which one should be applied for certain types of  images. moreover this solution gets the high accuracy for some cases. looks i need to combine all discussed in this topic for better result =)

Comment: Well I think I have a pretty good solution for you. Just need to convert it into an answer. I don't think the bounty should have been awarded already.

Answer (score 3):

I have a partial solution in place.

**FIRST**

I initially converted the image to the HSV color space and tinkered with the *value* channel. On doing so I came across something unique. In almost every image, the droplets have a tiny reflection of light. This was highlighted distinctly in the *value* channel.

Upon inverting this I was able to obtain the following:

Sample 1:

[image]

Sample 2:

[image]

Sample 3:

[image]

**SECOND**

Now we have to extract the location of those points. To do so I performed anomaly detection on the inverted value channel obtained. By anomaly I mean the black dot present in them.

In order to do this I calculated the **median** of the inverted value channel. I allotted pixel value within 70% above and below the median to be treated as normal pixels. But every pixel value lying beyond this range to be anomalies. The black dots fit perfectly there.

Sample 1:

[image]

Sample 2:

[image]

Sample 3:

[image]

It did not turn out well for few images.

As you can see the black dot is due to the reflection of light which is unique to the droplets of water. Other circular edges might be present in the image but the reflection distinguishes the droplet from those edges.

**THIRD**

Now since we have the location of these black dots, we can perform Difference of Gaussians (DoG) (also mentioned in the update of the question) and obtain relevant edge information. If the obtained location of the black dots lie within the edges discovered it is said to be a water droplet.

Disclaimer: This method does not work for all the images. You can add your suggestions to this.

Comment: thank you! it helps me to analyze the type of image and process or remove glares/overexposed areas when i need. thank you.

Comment: Sure, you have to just incorporate all the techniques you've come across

Comment: Nice idea @JeruLuke. I considered using the reflections too. But thought more about floodfill, that wouldn't work since some of the blobs' edges are not well defined. I actually have my own answer but can't post it since stackoverflow gives me an [error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292176/code-formatting-error).

Answer (score 0):

Good day , I am working on this subject and my advice to you is; First, after using many denoising filters such as Gaussian filters, process the image after that.
You can blob-detection these circles not with countors.

Comment: you may add an example